# Selenium RC (Python) only sends text to one tinymce control on page

Tags: javascript, python, selenium

I'm writing some automated test scripts using Python (2.7) with Selenium RC (2.42.1) for a page that contains multiple tinymce controls (2 to be precise). The code that I've been using up to date looks like the following:

```
sel.focus( field_values[ id_value ] + "_ifr" )
sel.get_eval( "window.parent.tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent('<p>" + 
               field_values[ test_data ] + "</p>');" )
```

To date, this code has worked fine for me, but after a recent build, I have been having issues when there are multiple copies of the tinymce control on the page. The setContent() function seems to always want to send the text to the second tinymce control, regardless of which ID I set the focus() to. And as a wonderful caveat, if I shrink my window frame so only the first tinymce control is visible on the screen, then only the first tinymce control gets sent any text.

My going theory right now is that the .activeEditor is not pointing to the right tinymce control when I set my content. It seems to always point to the last visible tinymce that it sees on the screen so I'm trying to find a way to force the focus to the appropriate tinymce control.

My question is, is there a better way to force the focus to the correct tinymce control using Python Selenium? I've tried using sel.click("tinymce") and sel.type_keys("tinymce","") after setting the focus(), but they don't seem to work.

I confirmed with the development team that no changes were made to the tinymce control, and I'm using the same Selenium RC version as always.

And I don't know if this will help, but there has been a push to move our automated testing over to a C# framework. We had the same issue as with the Python code, but we came up with a solution for that:

```
driver.SwitchTo().Frame(iWeb);

// This was added to ensure the tinymce control edit area has focus. This is necessary for pages that have multiple tinymce controls.
IWebElement body = driver.FindElement( By.TagName( "body" ) );
body.SendKeys( "" );

driver.Execute("window.parent.tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent('" + Test_Data + "');");

driver.SwitchTo().DefaultContent();
```

I want to be able to do the same thing, but with the Python code.

Comment: I suspect the HTML has duplicate `id` values for tinyMCE tags on the multiple widgets. Is it possible?

Comment: I thought of that too, but I confirmed that both <iframe> id values for the tinymce controls are different and unique. I also send the correct id value to the sel.focus() command when I attempt to write to each control, but the get_eval() statement always want to send the text to one control.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the reason why I could no longer handle multiple instances of TinyMCE controls on the same page. I recently had to rebuild my machine due to hardware problems, and in the process, I updated my Firefox browser to the latest ESR release (24.7.0). I rolled back to v24.2.0 with no issues. It seems there must have been a security update that was causing the unusual behaviour with my automated code. I'm still researching what updates were made and if it's actually possible to write to multiple TinyMCE's with the latest ESR version of Firefox.